# NextcloudPi SSH Login Connection immediately closed

Tags: ssh, nextcloud

I have installed Nextcloudpi on my Raspberry Pi 3. I downloaded the image from [ownyourbits](https://ownyourbits.com/nextcloudpi/) and flashed it to the SD card with [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). When I want to login with the standard ncp user via SSH the console shows the nextcloudpi logo and outputs this:

```
NextCloudPi v1.9.3 is outdated
update to v1.13.3 through 'ncp-config' or type 'sudo ncp-update'
Could not chdir to home directory /nonexistent: No such file or directory
This account is currently not available.
Connection to 192.xxx.xxx.xx closed.
```

I also cannot login as root user because no password is set. How can I solve this?

BTW the only reason I want to login via SSH is to the Raspberry to spin down the external hard drive after an hour or so.